# cURLing cPanel, not authenticating after login

Tags: php, api, curl, cpanel, libcurl

I'm sort of reinventing the wheel on this one, I know there are classes already written but I only need a very small subset of that functionality so I've decided to write my own class.

Ultimately my goal is to get a list of all email addresses created in cpanel. I plan to do that by curling the "Email addresses" page and checking for a "Next page" link.

I can log in ok, but when I make the second curl call to `/frontend/x3/mail/pops.html` I get a buncha gobbledegook back from the server instead of the source code for the emails page.

The libcurl generated cookie file works, writes the cookies and sends them back, so what else could be wrong?

This is my in-progress code:

```
class cpanel {
    var $cpanelHost;
    var $cpanelPort;
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $loggedin = false;
    var $logcurl = true;
    var $cookiefile = "cpanel_cookie.txt";
    var $curlfile = "cpanel_curl.txt";
    var $cpsess;
    var $homepage;

    function __construct($user,$pass,$host,$port="2083"){
        $this->cpanelHost = $host;
        $this->cpanelPort = $port;
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
        $this->LogIn($user,$pass);
    }

    function LogIn($username,$password){
        $params = 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password;
        $url = 'https://'.$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort."/login/?login_only=1";
        $headers = array(
            "Host: ".$this->cpanelHost,
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        );

        $answer = $this->Request($url,$headers,$params);
        //echo $answer; exit; //{"status":1,"redirect":"/cpsess8791005960/frontend/x3/index.html?post_login=92098211063688","security_token":"/cpsess8791005960"}
        $answer = json_decode($answer, true);
        $loggedin = (isset($answer['status']) && $answer['status'] == 1) ? true : false;
        $this->loggedin = $loggedin;
        if($this->loggedin){
            $this->cpsess = $answer['security_token'];
            $this->homepage = 'https://'.$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$answer['redirect'];
        }
    }

    function getEmails(){
        $params = '';
        $url = "https://".$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$this->cpsess."/frontend/x3/mail/pops.html";
        $headers = array(
            "Host: ".$this->homepage,
            "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        );
        $referrer = $this->homepage;
        $answer = $this->Request($url,$headers,$params);
        echo $answer; exit;
    }

    function Request($url,$headers=array(),$params=array(),$referrer=""){
        if($this->logcurl){
            $curl_log = fopen($this->curlfile, 'a+');
        }
        if(!file_exists($this->cookiefile)){
            echo 'Cookie file missing.'; exit;
        }else if(!is_writable($this->cookiefile)){
            echo 'Cookie file not writable.'; exit;
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0');
        if(!empty($headers)){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        if(!empty($params)){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($this->cookiefile));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($this->cookiefile));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        if($this->logcurl){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        if(!empty($referrer)){
           curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer);  
        }
        $answer = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_error($ch)) {
            $loggedin = curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        if($this->logcurl){
            fclose($curl_log);
        }
        return $answer;
    }

}
```

Comment: `var` is being depreciated. Use `public`, `private`, `protected`. Of course any of those could be `static` as well. Also, declare your functions.

Comment: Yeah, it's just good practice. I don't think that is your problem, though.

Comment: It's not, the class itself isn't throwing any syntax errors or anything, there must be something wrong with the actual request, I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it after realizing that cPanel's JSON API requires the username and password to be POSTed along with the GET parameters for each API call. If it helps anyone, my class is available [here](http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2014/07/using-cpanels-json-api-with-php-curl-to.html).

```
/**
 * cPanelMailManager
 * PHP Library for the email module of cPanel's JSON API
 * @author Rob Parham 
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014, Rob Parham
 * @license http://www.wtfpl.net/ WTF Public License
 */
class cPanelMailManager {
    public $cookiefile;
    private $cpanelHost;
    private $cpanelPort;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $logcurl;
    private $curlfile;
    private $emailArray;
    private $cpsess;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param string $user cPanel username
     * @param string $pass cPanel password
     * @param string $host cPanel domain
     * @param int $port cPanel domain
    */
    public function __construct($user,$pass,$host,$port=2083){
        $this->cpanelHost = $host;
        $this->cpanelPort = $port;
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
        $this->logcurl = false;
        $this->cookiefile = "cpmm/cpmm_cookie_".rand(99999, 9999999).".txt";
        $this->LogIn();
    }

    /**
     * Checks if an email address exists
     * @param string $Needle Email address to check
     * @param bool $FullEmailOnly If false, will return true with or without the domain attached
     * @return bool
    */
    public function emailExists($Needle, $FullEmailOnly = false){
        $Haystack = empty($this->emailArray) ? $this->getEmails() : $this->emailArray;
        foreach($Haystack as $H){
            if($FullEmailOnly === true && $H['email'] == $Needle){
                return true;
            }else if($FullEmailOnly !== true && ($H['user'] == $Needle || $H['email'] == $Needle)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new email address
     * @param string $email Complete mail address to create, ie. myemail@mydomain.com
     * @param string $password Password for new email
     * @param string $quota Disk Space Quota, 0 for unlimited
     * @return bool
    */
    public function createEmail($email,$password,$quota = 0){
        if($this->emailExists($email,true)){
            return "Email address ".$email." already exist";
        }
        $e = explode("@",$email);
        $params = 'user='.$this->username.'&pass='.$this->password;;
        $url = "https://".$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$this->cpsess."/json-api/cpanel".
        "?cpanel_jsonapi_version=2".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_func=addpop".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email&".
        "email=".$e[0]."&".
        "domain=".$e[1]."&".
        "password=".urlencode($password)."&".
        "quota=".$quota;
        $answer = json_decode($this->Request($url,$params), true);
        $this->getEmails(true);
        return ($answer["cpanelresult"]["data"][0]['result'] === 1) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an email address
     * @param string $email Complete mail address to delete, ie. myemail@mydomain.com
     * @return bool
    */
    public function deleteEmail($email){
        if(!$this->emailExists($email,true)){
            return "Email address ".$email." does not exist";
        }
        $e = explode("@",$email);
        $params = 'user='.$this->username.'&pass='.$this->password;;
        $url = "https://".$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$this->cpsess."/json-api/cpanel".
        "?cpanel_jsonapi_version=2".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_func=delpop".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email&".
        "email=".$e[0]."&".
        "domain=".$e[1];
        $answer = json_decode($this->Request($url,$params), true);
        $this->getEmails(true);
        return ($answer["cpanelresult"]["data"][0]['result'] === 1) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Changes a password
     * @param string $email Complete email of account, ie. myemail@mydomain.com
     * @param string $newPW New password
     * @return bool
    */
    public function changePW($email, $newPW){
        if(!$this->emailExists($email,true)){
            return "Email address ".$email." does not exist";
        }
        $e = explode("@",$email);
        $params = 'user='.$this->username.'&pass='.$this->password;;
        $url = "https://".$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$this->cpsess."/json-api/cpanel".
        "?cpanel_jsonapi_version=2".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_func=passwdpop".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email&".
        "email=".$e[0]."&".
        "domain=".$e[1]."&".
        "password=".urlencode($newPW);
        $answer = json_decode($this->Request($url,$params), true);
        $this->getEmails(true);
        return ($answer["cpanelresult"]["data"][0]['result'] === 1) ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Lists all email accounts and their properties
     * @param int $pageSize Number of results per page
     * @param int $currentPage Page number to start from
     * @param bool $paginate Return in pages
     * @param bool $sort Sort the results
     * @param bstring $sortby Column to sort by, ie. "email", "_diskused", "mtime", or "domain"
     * @return array
    */
    public function listEmails($pageSize = 10, $currentPage = 1, $paginate = true, $sort = true, $sortby = "user"){
        $params = 'user='.$this->username.'&pass='.$this->password;;
        $url = "https://".$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$this->cpsess."/json-api/cpanel".
        "?cpanel_jsonapi_version=2".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_func=listpopswithdisk".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email".
        "&api2_paginate=".($paginate === false ? 0 : 1).
        "&api2_paginate_size=".$pageSize.
        "&api2_paginate_start=".$currentPage.
        "&api2_sort=".($sort === false ? 0 : 1).
        "&api2_sort_column=".$sortby.
        "&api2_sort_method=alphabet".
        "&api2_sort_reverse=0";
        $answer = $this->Request($url,$params);
        $emails = json_decode($answer, true);
        $this->emailArray = $emails["cpanelresult"]["data"];
        return $this->emailArray;
    }

    /**
     * Turns cURL logging on
     * @param int $curlfile Path to curl log file
     * @return array
    */
    public function logCurl($curlfile = "cpmm/cpmm_curl_log.txt"){
        if(!file_exists($curlfile)){
            try{
                fopen($curlfile, "w");
            }catch(Exception $ex){
                if(!file_exists($curlfile)){
                    return $ex.'Cookie file missing.'; exit;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }else if(!is_writable($curlfile)){
            return 'Cookie file not writable.'; exit;
        }
        $this->logcurl = true;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a complete list of emails and their properties
     * @access private
    */
    private function getEmails($refresh = false){
        if(!empty($this->emailArray) && !$refresh){
            return $this->emailArray;
        }
        $params = 'user='.$this->username.'&pass='.$this->password;;
        $url = "https://".$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$this->cpsess."/json-api/cpanel".
        "?cpanel_jsonapi_version=2".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_func=listpopswithdisk".
        "&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Email";
        $answer = $this->Request($url,$params);
        $emails = json_decode($answer, true);
        $this->emailArray = $emails["cpanelresult"]["data"];
        return $this->emailArray;
    }

    /**
     * Starts a session on the cPanel server
     * @access private
    */
    private function LogIn(){
        $url = 'https://'.$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort."/login/?login_only=1";
        $url .= "&user=".$this->username."&pass=".urlencode($this->password);
        $answer = $this->Request($url);
        $answer = json_decode($answer, true);
        if(isset($answer['status']) && $answer['status'] == 1){
            $this->cpsess = $answer['security_token'];
            $this->homepage = 'https://'.$this->cpanelHost.":".$this->cpanelPort.$answer['redirect'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes an HTTP request
     * @access private
    */
    private function Request($url,$params=array()){
        if($this->logcurl){
            $curl_log = fopen($this->curlfile, 'a+');
        }
        if(!file_exists($this->cookiefile)){
            @fopen($this->cookiefile, "w");
            if(!file_exists($this->cookiefile)){
                echo 'Cookie file missing. '.$this->cookiefile; exit;
            }
        }else if(!is_writable($this->cookiefile)){
            echo 'Cookie file not writable. '.$this->cookiefile; exit;
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        $curlOpts = array(
            CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0',
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => realpath($this->cookiefile),
            CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => realpath($this->cookiefile),
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
                "Host: ".$this->cpanelHost,
                "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                "Connection: keep-alive",
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        );
        if(!empty($params)){
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $params;
        }
        if($this->logcurl){
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_STDERR] = $curl_log;
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_FAILONERROR] = false;
            $curlOpts[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = true;
        }
        curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOpts);
        $answer = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_error($ch)) {
            echo curl_error($ch); exit;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        if($this->logcurl){
            fclose($curl_log);
        }
        return (@gzdecode($answer)) ? gzdecode($answer) : $answer;
    }
}
```